# Can I select an nth css column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I have a `div` with 4 css `columns` and I'd like to select the 3rd and 4th column to make the text slightly darker because I don't have a good contrast between the text and the `background-image`. Is this possible? I can accept any css or js solution.

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8fKs5/).

**--EDIT--**

It seems that it's not possible to find a selector for *pseudo blocks* (if I may say) however I still need to figure out a way of creating responsive blocks (like columns) that will split the text equally (in width) whenever the browser is resized.

Comment: as far as I know, there is no way to do that

Comment: There isn't (*[yet](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#nth-column-pseudo)*) an implemented means to do this.

Comment: @David I thought so. That's why I'm trying to figure out a way of doing this with js. Even if the script creates blocks other than css columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know you won't be able to apply styles to the columns.
What you can try however is to use a gradient as a background to make columns 3 and 4 another color.

```
#columns {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, blue 50%);
    /*... appropriate css for other browser engines*/
}
```

[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fKs5/4/)
updated with all browser support gradient

**-- EDIT --**

Since the intention was actually to change the text color and not the background for the third and fourth column some additional thoughts.

For now it doesn't seem possible to apply styles to single columns inside a container. One possible workaround to change the text color in specific columns is to put every word inside a `span`. Then to use JavaScript to iterate over the words and determine where a new column starts. Assigning the first element in the third column a new class would make it possible to style this and the following siblings with a different text color.

Because the container is part of a responsive layout and could change in size, the script would have to be re-run on the resize event to account for changing column widths.

The purpose of the code example is to outline how to implement such a solution and should be improved for use in an actual application (e.g. the `span`s are being re-created every time `styleCols` is run, lots of console output...).

**JavaScript**

```
function styleCols() {
    // get #columns
    var columns = document.getElementById('columns');
    // split the text into words
    var words = columns.innerText.split(' ');
    // remove the text from #columns
    columns.innerText = '';

    // readd the text to #columns with one span per word
    var spans = []
    for (var i=0;i<words.length;i++) {
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerText = words[i] + ' ';
        spans.push(span);
        columns.appendChild(span);
    }

    // offset of the previous word
    var prev = null;
    // offset of the column
    var colStart = null;
    // number of the column
    var colCount = 0;
    // first element with a specific offset
    var firsts = [];
    // loop through the spans
    for (var i=0;i<spans.length;i++) {
        var first = false;
        var oL = spans[i].offsetLeft;
        console.info(spans[i].innerText, oL);
        // test if this is the first span with this offset
        if (firsts[oL] === undefined) {
            console.info('-- first');
            // add span to firsts
            firsts[oL] = spans[i];
            first = true;
        }
        // if the offset is smaller or equal to the previous offset this
        // is a new line
        // if the offset is also greater than the column offset we are in
        // (the second row of) a new column
        if ((prev === null || oL <= prev) && (colStart === null || oL > colStart)) {
            console.info('-- col++', colCount + 1);
            // update the column offset
            colStart = oL;
            // raise the column count
            colCount++;
        }
        // if we have reached the third column
        if (colCount == 3) {
            // add our new class to the first span with the column offset
            // (this is the first span in the current column
            firsts[oL].classList.add('first-in-col3');
            return;
        }
        // update prev to reflect the current offset
        prev = oL;
    }
}
styleCols();
addEventListener('resize', styleCols, false);
```

**CSS**

```
.first-in-col3, .first-in-col3~span {
    color: red;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fKs5/7/)

Comment: That's not bad, an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I'm looking to change the text color of the nth column. If I use background fill I'll hide the background image.

Comment: Ok that's a tough one and I can't think of any CSS solutions. Perhaps you can try to determine which words/letters are in which column via JS and dynamically wrap the content of the relevant columns into a `span` and style that?

Comment: ..and to make it even tougher, the `div` is responsive. So, I can't really count the words/letters because the width of each column changes accordingly.

Comment: Yes. A script like that would probably had to be rerun on every resize event. For now it is probably best to change the background/font color or to give `#columns` a semi transparent background to achieve a high enough contrast. And to hope that the feature request that dakait mentioned gets implemented soon.

Comment: Nice approach. It gives me an idea of how to implement. Thanks hsan!

Answer (score 3):

For now i dont think you can do it, here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=371323 is an open bug/request for a feature, you can vote for it. Till then you can consider using tables.

P.S.

[Give Up and Use Tables](http://giveupandusetables.com/) just for the sake of humor :)

Comment: well... tables was my second thought but if I could at least make them with css tables it'd be better. But still I face the same nth selector issue with `display:table-column`

Answer (score 1):

The only solution i could think would be a background with your desired color for middle column, customize it for size and position so it goes behind your middle columns and make `background-clip:text`. Unfortunately it is not supported very well.
You can find more explenations [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/12/experiments-with-background-clip-text/).

Comment: very promising although it lacks compatibility.