# How to access single column which created with css3 columns?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `div.masonry` with some items.

```
<div class="masonry">
    <div class="item">some text<div>
    <div class="item">some text<div>
    <div class="item">some text<div>
 ...
</div>
```

I styled this div using css3 columns.

```
.masonry {
-moz-column-count: 5;
 }
```

and items correctly divided in 5 columns.

Now I want to get access to items and style them by their column number.
for example first column items become blue, second red , and so on....

And I want do this just with jQuery.

Help me.

Comment: I doubt if this is possible...

Comment: Basically, there is no CSS selector for this. The columns are not elements and so cannot be selected by CSS (or javascript as I understand it).

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270509/can-i-select-an-nth-css-column

Comment: @Passerby so can i just divide them in my jqurey file with something else like left offsets or positions ?

Comment: @Paulie_D thank you for replays :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry my previous answer was based on a misunderstanding of columns.
You could try something like this:

```
var numCol = $('.masonry').css('column-count');
var numElem = $('.masonry .item1').length;
var elemPerCol = numElem / numCol;

for( var i = 0; i < numCol; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < elemPerCol; j++){
        if(i==0){
            $('.masonry .item1').eq(j+(i*elemPerCol)).css('color', 'red');                
        }
        else if(i==1){
            $('.masonry .item1').eq(j+(i*elemPerCol)).css('color', 'blue');    
        }
        else if(i==2){
            $('.masonry .item1').eq(j+(i*elemPerCol)).css('color', 'green');    
        }
        else if(i==3){
            $('.masonry .item1').eq(j+(i*elemPerCol)).css('color', 'purple');    
        }
        else if(i==4){
            $('.masonry .item1').eq(j+(i*elemPerCol)).css('color', 'black');    
        }
    }
}
```

It will break if you don't have an equal number of elements per column though.

http://jsfiddle.net/dk2g41qm/7/

Comment: [CSS columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts) may not mean what you thought...

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't realised.

Comment: Fixed my answer to work with css columns

Comment: @gaynorvader thank you for your answer... the problem now is that the number of items in each column is not equal .... items have different height so we cant say "elemPerCol " is ture !
any suggestion ? :(

Comment: When I added extra items, the columns went down to 4 for some reason, is this happening for you?

Comment: @gaynorvader@passerby
i figure it out :)) thank you anyway:)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dk2g41qm/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can try below jquery to do so. Help this works.

```
var colors = ["blue", "red", "green"];
var j=0;
$('.masonry .item').each(function(){
   $(this).css('color',colors[j]);
   j++;
   if(j>$(this).length){j=0;}
});
```

Comment: number of items is more than 100... it means in each column i have about 20 items... so , running your code... colors[ j ] for j>2 will not going to be excuted

Comment: so if you want to repeat set of colors on those items, then try the updated answer.

Comment: that would be ok if items divide one after other...
it is not like that ...items will divide randomly, i mean first column will fill first then second then... and i dont have items count.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pseudoselector `:nth-child(x)`. [Here's the documentation.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

[Here's a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQROzK) with what you want to achieve. I hope you understand that it is bad practice to use JavaScript to style elements. But I suppose if you are using `-moz-column-count` you have a good reason to do so.

Comment: You may misunderstood OP's question: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BopZqx

Comment: You are right!


I didn't realise they could span multiple lines. You could match the first column using `:nth-child(-n+NUMBER_OF_LINES)` but that is not flexible enough, I guess